# How to call a class function from within another classes extension in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So say if I have a Class A. Then I create a new swift file for class B where it would look like this:

```
extension Class A {

 public Class B: Superclass {

  public class func doSomething() { }

 }

}
```

Now how would I make the call to `doSomething()` ?

Comment: Calling it from another separate Swift class. Lets say Class C for example.

Comment: Create a variable with Class B type in Class A and make it accessible as a public variable or through a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add an inner class to an existing class via an extension, you can do it like this:

```
public class A {

}

public extension A {

    public class B {

        public class func doSomething() {
            print("hello")
        }

    }

}
```

Note there is no `Superclass` involved.

Since `doSomething` is a class method, you can call it like this:

```
A.B.doSomething() // "hello"
```

If you are trying to define a subclass of `A`, then you should do this:

```
public class A {

}

public class B: A {

        public class func doSomething() {
            print("hello")
        }

}

B.doSomething() // "hello"
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, which wasn't working initially. It turns out it wasn't working because Xcode was not finding the subdirectory which contained Class B. I have since fixed that and it now works. I consider the problem might have been Swift related because I just switched to it and am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

How do you feel about this:

```
 public class A {
        var innerClass = InnerClass()
 }

extension A {
    public class InnerClass {   
            public class func doSomething() { }
    }   
}

public class C {
    var test = A().innerClass
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to access the method without modifying the existing classes. Reason is these classes will get updated in the future externally and I don't want to have to modify anything on my end.